# Casting a custom collection using as fails

Tags: c#, casting, icollection

I have a custom Collection as follows: (I wont show all the code of the class)

```
public class MyCollection : IList<MyOBject>, ICollection<MyOBject>, IEnumerable<MyOBject>, IEnumerable, IDisposable
{
    //Constructor
    public MyCollection (MyOBject[] shellArray);
    // blah blah
}
```

I only want entries in the collection where SomeValue=false and I am trying to work out why I cannot use the **as** operator as follows:

```
MyCollection SortCollection(MyCollection collection)
{
    MyCollection test1 = collection.Where(x => (bool)x["SomeValue"].Equals(false)) as MyCollection ; //test1 = null

    var test2 = collection.Where(x => (bool)x["SomeValue"].Equals(false)) as MyCollection ;          //test2 = null

    var test3 = collection.Where(x => (bool)x["SomeValue"].Equals(false)); //test3 is non null and can be used
    return new MyCollection (test3.ToArray());
}
```

Why can I not use the code in **test1** and **test2**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are mistakenly thinking the result of `MyCollection.Where` is an `MyCollection`. It is not, it is `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is the item type, which is `MyOBject` in this case.

This code should work:

```
IEnumerable<MyOBject> test1 = collection.Where(x => (bool)x["SomeValue"].Equals(false));
```

You might want to feed that back to your `MyCollection` constructor:

```
MyCollection coll = new MyCollection(test1.ToArray());
```